# Gravity Form - expiration date with year

Tags: javascript, php

I need help with this code. This code's output is example "21st of June". I would like to add year on that. How can I insert that in the code as I got an invalid code when I added the 'Y':)

```js
add_filter( 'gform_field_value', 'all_the_dates', 10, 3 );
function all_the_dates( $value, $field, $name,  ) {
    // "21st of June" is the format we want
    $local_timestamp = GFCommon::get_local_timestamp( time() );
    $expiration_timestamp = ( 86400 * 182 ) + $local_timestamp;
    $today = date_i18n( 'jS \of F', $local_timestamp, true );
    $expiration = date_i18n( 'jS \of F', $expiration_timestamp, true );
    $values = array(
        'todays_date' => $today,
        'three_days'  => $three,
        '182_days'  => $expiration,
    );
    return isset( $values[ $name ] ) ? $values[ $name ] : $value;
}
```

Appreciate any input as soon as anyone can :)
Thank you!!!

Cheers,
Liza

Comment: What error? You need to give appropriate details.

Comment: Hi sorry. 

I changed this *'jS \of F'* to this *'jS \of F Y D'* (added the Y D) to get this format *"21st of June 2022"* result and when I hit save the website went down :) So I guess that was an invalid code.

Comment: Why would you add the `D`? `Y` already is the full year. `D` is the 3 letter abbreviation of the day of the week. But regardless of what format you specify, this should not cause an error in _this_ place. But we don't know what happens with these values afterwards (maybe the get used by the system in another place, that expected the previous format?), and not is "website went down" a _precise_ problem description either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is coming from the fact that $three is undefined: 'three_days' => $three, Remove that line and see if your site still receives an error.

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value', 'all_the_dates', 10, 3 );
    function all_the_dates( $value, $field, $name,  ) {
        // "21st of June" is the format we want
        $local_timestamp = GFCommon::get_local_timestamp( time() );
        $expiration_timestamp = ( 86400 * 182 ) + $local_timestamp;
        $today = date_i18n( 'jS \of F Y', $local_timestamp, true );
        $expiration = date_i18n( 'jS \of F Y', $expiration_timestamp, true );
        $values = array(
            'todays_date' => $today,
            '182_days'  => $expiration,
        );
        return isset( $values[ $name ] ) ? $values[ $name ] : $value;
    }
```